# React PropTypes - How to make a shape optional with its fields required?

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I have a component that receives a `badge` prop (see example down below). The badge is optional, but once it is used I want it to have some required fields inside it. I've tried the following:

```
Component.propTypes = {
  badge: PropTypes.shape({
    src: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    alt: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  }),
}
```

It works, but I get this warning on Chrome when trying to use it without the badge:

> Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `badge.src` is marked as required
>   in `Component`, but its value is `null`.

What is the proper way of doing this?

---

#### Component usage example:

[image: Barack Obama with flag] `badge={{ src: 'usa.png', alt: 'United States' }}`

---

[image: Barack Obama without flag] `badge` not supplied

Comment: Shouldn't you declare it as a separate (optional) component, and then for that component define the props as required?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This *is* the correct way to do this. I was very intrigued by how this wouldn't work, so I pasted it in a CodePen (https://codepen.io/Oblosys/pen/xLvxrd) and it works just as expected. (Open a console, and uncomment the failing one to see a prop-type error)

Something else must be going wrong in your code, and at some point you render a `Component` with a badge property object that has `src: null`. Maybe before data from an api request has arrived? With some console logging in `Component` and its parent, you should be able to find the culprit.

Comment: Yup, it works! I realized the default prop for `badge` was `{src: null, alt: null}` hahaha. Thanks!